# What does the phrase "held in confidence" mean?

Tags: meaning

I recently came across this sentence:

> Thank them for their time and remind them that answers will be held in
>   confidence.

Simplifying things, if I said "Your answers will be held in confidence", what exactly would that mean? Does it mean that I have confidence *in* their answers? What does it mean to hold their answers (or anything) in confidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the content of their answer will not be told to other people:

***[in confidence](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--confidence)***:

> as a secret or private matter, not to be divulged or communicated to others; with belief in a person's sense of discretion.

(Dictionary.com)